# Как получить значение тега из Properties?

Tags: python, requests, bs4

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Мне нужно получить текст из Properties -> outerText

Используя requests и bs4

Comment: Прокси добываем:) А где ваша попытка в виде кода?

Comment: Я не знаю как получить это значение, поэтому смысл от моего кода где просто запрос к сайту и немного парсинга.

Comment: https://advanced.name/ Динамический сайт по тегам которые вы выдете в браузере вы не найдете прокси с портами.

Comment: Я так понял это сделать нет возможности?

Comment: попробывать достать через селенимум